React, useContext стоит ли передавать setState в Provider?
Мой DOM таков:GlobalContext -> List -> ListItem. У каждого ListItem есть onDelete событие. Использую useContext на самом верхнем уровне. Есть отдельный компонент GlobalContext на верхнем уровне который хранит состояние в виде простого списка и передает его ниже.  List компонент берет его и возвращает ListItem компоненты на основе данных из этого списка. Вопрос в том, стоит ли реализовать handleDeleteListItem в GlobalContext компоненте чтобы передать прямо в ListItem элементе, или стоит передать (Provider) setState этого листа и реализовать handleDeleteItem(id) в List компоненте и передать пропсом? Глубина в 1 элемент, никакого Props drilling нету, но какие лучшие практики? стоит ли setState передавать в Provider?

Что бы читалось, лучше все управление состоянием сделать в том компоненте, который это состояние хранит, а компонент(ниже) просто должен говорить родителю - сделай то то.

@SwaD Т.е. компонент в котором useContext реализован должна быть вся логика?

Ну если вы потом не хотите удивляться, что и откуда лезет у вас, то да. Компонент со своими данными должен работать на подобии АПИ. Он данные раздает и он же получает команды на их изменение. Остальные компоненты работают только с тем, что родитель вернул(допустимо преобразование для дочерненго компонента).

@SwaD А что делать в случае, когда компонент имеет черезчур много handler-функций для изменения объекта? допустим не только изменения на верхнем уровне объекта, а на ещё большей вложенности (т.е. объект хранящий объекты которые нужно тоже обновлять, а то и ещё глубже)  CardItem => item => subitem => subsubitem. и каждый из них имеет свои обработчики событий (onDelete) и данные для их отображения хранятся в самом верху DOM дерева в одном объекте который я описал выше в сообщении

Переходить на redux и постараться декомпозировать логику хранения данных. Один гигантский объект с ветвлениями - ну так себе затея. Тут надо смотреть на саму структуру проекта и структуру данных. Пока это так, теория и мнение

@SwaD Понял спасибо, у меня объект в виде карточки-вопроса, и вложенным объектом в нем является массив из изменяемых карточек-ответов, и у меня очень много логики с манимуляцией именно над этим объектом-массивом и объектами в нем, нужно сделать handlerAddAnswer, handlerDeleteAnswer, handleChangeAnswer и.т.д. Т.е. делаю конструктор вопросников, где создаю карточку-вопрос, и создаю в нем карточки-ответы и их заполняю
